# What are the divisors of $2n^2 - \sigma_{1}(n^2)$ for composite $n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, open-problems, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

What are the divisors of $2n^2 - \sigma_{1}(n^2)$ for composite $n$?

Here, $\sigma_{1}$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function.  For example, $\sigma_{1}(3^2) = 1 + 3 + {3^2} = 13$.

(The function $D(x) = 2x - \sigma_{1}(x)$ is called the *deficiency* of $x$ [see [OEIS Sequence A033879](http://oeis.org/A033879)].)

Now, for the motivation behind the question:

Let $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ be an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form (i.e., $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q, n) = 1$).

Since $N$ is perfect, we have the equation

$$\sigma_{1}(N) = 2N \Longleftrightarrow \sigma_{1}({q^k}{n^2}) = \sigma_{1}(q^k)\sigma_{1}(n^2) = 2{q^k}{n^2}.$$

We can express $\sigma_{1}(q^k)$ as

$$\sigma_{1}(q^k) = 1 + q + \ldots + q^{k-1} + q^k = \left(1 + q + \ldots + q^{k-1}\right) + q^k = \sigma_{1}(q^{k-1}) + q^k$$

whereupon we have

$$\sigma_{1}(q^k)\sigma_{1}(n^2) = \left(\sigma_{1}(q^{k-1}) + {q^k} \right)\sigma_{1}(n^2) = 2{q^k}{n^2}.$$

Dividing through by $q^k$ in

$$\left(\sigma_{1}(q^{k-1}) + {q^k} \right)\sigma_{1}(n^2) = 2{q^k}{n^2},$$

we get

$$2n^2 - \sigma_{1}(n^2) = I(q^{k-1})\cdot{\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}},$$

where

$$I(x) = \frac{\sigma_{1}(x)}{x}$$

is the *abundancy index* of $x$.

From the last equation, since $q \geq 5$ implies $1 \leq I(q^{k-1}) < \frac{5}{4} = 1.25$, we have the biconditional

$$k = 1 \Longleftrightarrow 2n^2 - \sigma_{1}(n^2) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}.$$

In other words, we have the biconditional

$$k = 1 \Longleftrightarrow 2n^2 - \sigma_{1}(n^2) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}.$$

[In the paper [The Abundancy Index of Divisors of Odd Perfect Numbers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), the assertion $k = 1$ for odd perfect numbers $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ was called as Sorli's conjecture -- although, in a more recent (proceedings) paper by B. Beasley of Presbyterian College, titled [Euler and the Ongoing Search for Odd Perfect Numbers](http://godandmath.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/acms-2013-proceedings.pdf), he points out that it was in fact Descartes who initially made this conjecture (in a letter to Marin Mersenne in 1638), "with Frenicle's subsequent observation occurring in 1657".]

Now, following [Broughan, et. al.](http://www.emis.de/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf), it is known that the index $\frac{\sigma_{1}(n^2)}{q^k}$ of the Euler factor $q^k$ satisfies

$$\frac{\sigma_{1}(n^2)}{q^k} \geq 315,$$

and

$$\frac{\sigma_{1}(n^2)}{q^k}$$

cannot take any of the $11$ forms

$$\{p, p^2, p^3, p^4, p^5, p^6, {p_1}{p_2}, {p_1}^2{p_2}, {p_1}^3{p_2}, {p_1}^2{p_2}^2, {p_1}{p_2}{p_3}\}$$

where $p$ is any odd prime and $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are any distinct odd primes.

Now back to the original question:  We want to know the divisors of $2n^2 - \sigma_{1}(n^2)$ for composite $n$.

Note that, if $n$ is *prime*, say $r$, then we have

$$2n^2 - \sigma_{1}(n^2) = 2r^2 - \sigma_{1}(r^2) = 2r^2 - (r^2 + r + 1) = r^2 - r - 1 = r(r - 1) - 1,$$

which is, in general, odd (so that $2r^2 - \sigma_{1}(r^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ for $r$ prime.)  [In fact, since $\sigma_{1}(n^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ for all positive integers $n$, then we have $2n^2 - \sigma_{1}(n^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ for all positive integers $n$.]

Of course, the situation is more complicated when $\omega(n) \geq 2$ (where $\omega(x)$ is the number of *distinct* prime factors of $x$).

Comment: I suppose as $n$ varies the divisors vary also, what is exactly your question? I doubt closed form for the divisors of the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, @joro.  I am likewise highly skeptical that a closed form exists for the divisors of $2n^2 - \sigma_{1}(n^2)$, but obtaining results similar to Broughan, et. al. (and Chen and Chen) would be more to the spirit of my question.

Comment: Chen and Chen have a new paper titled [On the index of an odd perfect number](http://journals.impan.gov.pl/cm/Inf/136-1-4.html), where they extend Broughan, et. al.'s results.

Comment: These MSE links are related to this MO question: [On Descartes numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205692) and [On odd perfects and spoofs](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208762).